# Rel в в тегах HTML5

Tags: html, html5

Всем привет!
Обращаюсь с может быть глупым вопросом, но все же.
Совсем недавно мне стало не понятно то, что я использую и для чего мне это вообще нужно. Например тег link, с помощью которого можно получать доступ к CSS файлам. Внутри него я обычно пишу такой код: `< link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>`. Отсюда вопрос. Для чего нужен **rel**?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы браузер понимал, что хочешь добавить именно стили для страницы.
http://htmlbook.ru/html/link/rel

Предвижу вопрос типа "Все же указано в type". В type указан тип получаемых данных. Этих типов существует целая куча http://htmlbook.ru/html/value/mime и браузеру необходимо знать как читать этот документ.

Comment: @Get благодарю